# Number addition within a range (overflowing)

Tags: lua, numbers

Me again. That's right. Back at it with more rookie mistakes. Heh.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this, because I am having bad luck in my attempts and require assistance from someone more... able to problem solve than me.

I wish to have a function like this:

```
local function numberAddWithinRange(numberStart, add, min, max)
    local x;numberStart = numberStart + add;

    if numberStart<min then
        x = min + (numberStart*(numberStart>0 and -1 or 1)); -- - numberStart;
        return numberAddWithinRange(max, -x, min, max);
    elseif numberStart>max then
        x = min + (numberStart*(numberStart>0 and -1 or 1));-- - numberStart;
        print("X is:", x);
        return numberAddWithinRange(min, x, min, max);
    else
        x = numberStart;
    end;
    return x;

end;
```

This works okay, ***sort-of.***

You see, what I want it to do is that when I add let's say 245 to 20, with a range of 25, and 50, it adds it over and over going from 25 -> 50, 25 -> 50 until it reaches the point where all the of "overflowed" numbers have been used and then it returns the number leftover.  (if max == 50, then 51 becomes 26 and then continues adding, etc.)

However, my function doesn't seem to do it correctly, and whether it is night time or something I can't figure out how to fix it.

For reference, "after2" should be equal to the "startNum" but it isn't.

```
local startNum = 200;
local after = numberAddWithinRange(startNum, 400, 33, 127);
local after2 = numberAddWithinRange(after, -400, 33, 127);
print(after, after2, after2==startNum)
```

I've looked around, both on Google and on stackoverflow, and haven't found anything to help me with this.
I'm probably just being dumb... but hopefully there's someone who can help me.

I also do know that I could do this:

```
local gn = function(num, add, min, max)
    for i=add<0 and -1 or 1, add do
        num = num + (1 * (add<0 and -1 or 1));
        if num > max then
            num = min;
        elseif num < min then
            num = max;
        end;
    end;
    return num;
end;
```

However, that seems to me that it would be very inefficient, so anyone more knowledgeable: please help.

Comment: `(num + add - min)%(max - min + 1) + min`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff what's that for?

oof. I guess I'm bad. Thanks. lol.